# Cisco Anyconnect: Is there anyway to save password, username and VPN address?

Tags: lubuntu, cisco

[Cisco annyconnect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RDNDf.png)
Is there anyway that i don't have to put username,password and VPN address every time i login?

Answer (score 3):

In order to fix this you can add a profile for `Cisco AnyCOnnect Secure Mobility Client`.

In my case this implied adding a `profile.xml` in `/opt/cisco/anyconnect/profile` having a configuration like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<AnyConnectProfile xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/encoding/">
<ServerList>
     <HostEntry>
          <User>your username</User>
          <HostName>your hostname</HostName>
          <HostAddress>you host url</HostAddress>
     </HostEntry>
</ServerList>
</AnyConnectProfile>
```

Comment: where is the password

Comment: Since this does nothing related to a password it seems unlikely this answers the OP's question right? If it only partially answers it it would be nice to comment on that in the answer.